# Understanding using a method in map in Scala

Tags: scala

Why does the line of `asdf1` work in

```
  def trytoDouble(s: String): Option[Double] = {
    try {
      Some(s.toDouble)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => None
    }
  }

val asdf1 = Source.fromFile("data/my.csv").getLines().map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).map(trytoDouble(_)))

val asdf2 = Source.fromFile("data/my.csv").getLines().map(_.split(",").map(trytoDouble(_.trim)))
```

while the line of `asdf2` gives me the error message

> Type mismatch, expected String => NotInferedB, actual: Option[Double]

for `trytoDouble`?

Comment: I would go with a more fp solution to define trytoDouble

Comment: Something more like this : `def tryToDouble(s: String) : Option[Double] = scala.util.Try(s.toDouble).toOption`

Comment: @eliasah: Actually, I am getting a mismatch error then...

Comment: this is more idiomatic. Where are you getting the error ? `scala> Array("s,2. , 3 ").map(_.split(",").map(x => tryToDouble(x.trim)))
res11: Array[Array[Option[Double]]] = Array(Array(None, Some(2.0), Some(3.0)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplified your problem to see the point :

```
val oneLine = "line1, 13, 14, 15"               //> oneLine  : String = line1, 13, 14, 15
oneLine.split(",").map(_.trim)                  //> res2: Array[String] = Array(line1, 13, 14, 15)
```

This line works

```
 oneLine.split(",").map(s => trytoDouble(s.trim))//> res3: Array[Option[Double]] = Array(None, Some(13.0), Some(14.0), Some(15.0
```

But this line does not :

```
oneLine.split(",").map(trytoDouble(_.trim))
```

This is it because the compiler doesn't know how to infer the type of _ here, regarding the trim extension on String and the trytoDouble type.
The compiler message is :

```
 missing parameter type for expanded function
```

If you omit the trim, it's works :

```
  oneLine.split(",").map(trytoDouble(_))          //> res3: Array[Option[Double]] = Array(None, Some(13.0), Some(14.0), Some(15.0
```

The inference type system, in scala, is limited. You come rapidely to this kind of situation where you have to help it.

**Edit:**

The placeholder is always replaced in the smallest containning expression.

In fact,

```
 oneLine.split(",").map(trytoDouble(_.trim))
```

is replaced by :

```
oneLine.split(",").map(trytoDouble(x => x.trim))
```

but what you want is :

```
oneLine.split(",").map( x => trytoDouble(x.trim))
```

Comment: So basically, the compiler could know how to infer the type, but it just isn't smart enough yet, or does can it not know, because of logical reasons? After all the `_` is just syntactic sugar for the `s => ` version, is it not?

Comment: I have edited my post. I have also proposed to close the question because i've found an old one that asks for the same thing, i think

Comment: Thanks - you explanation is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Because after calling `tryToDouble` It will return `Iterator[Array[Option[Double]]]`, and you are trying to trim value of type `Option[Double]`. `trim` is not a member of `Option[Double]`. `trim` expects string but it finds Option[Double] type value. That's why it throws an error

```
Type mismatch, expected String => NotInferedB, actual: Option[Double]
```

You can't apply trim on Option[Double]. That's why first method works because there you apply trim on string.

Comment: For `asfd2`: `.split(",")` returns an Array of Strings, so the `_` in `.map(utils.trytoDouble(_.trim))` is a String, which we trim. This String (`_.trim`) is put as the input of `trytoDouble`. The term `utils.trytoDouble(_.trim)` then outputs of type `Option[Double]`. This is what I thought. I don't understand how `trim` would be applied to a Double in my code.

Comment: I have tested in scala repl, it gave me error, not found utils

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I corrected the code above.

Comment: Yes, so my answer explains why it won't work as tryToDouble will return Array[Option[Double]]. And you are applying trim to Option[Double]

Comment: 1) `tryToDouble` returns `Option[Double]`, not `Array[Option[Double]]`. 2) I apply tryToDoulbe *after* I applied `trim`. First `trim` gets a `String` and returns a `String`. Then `tryToDouble` is applied to that String. Maybe I don't understand your explanation - sorry.

Comment: Yes tryToDouble returns Option[Double]. Since you are applying tryToDouble to Array[String] so end result would be Array[Option [Double]]. Trim is a member of string not Double value. So you can't apply it.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation seems to be wrong. Please check out the explanation of volia17

Comment: Okay No problem.